# Apply datatables empty table message across all columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

Currently I have the following table set up:

```
<table id="add_users_table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="add_users_checkbox_all" value=""></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('#add_users_table').dataTable({
    "order": [],
    "columnDefs": [
        {"targets": [0,1], "width": "10%"},
        {"targets": [2,3], "width": "40%"},
        {"targets": 0, "orderable": false},
        {className: "text-center", "targets": [0, 1]}
     ],
     "language": {
        "zeroRecords": "<i>No new users are available to add</i>"
     },
     "ajax": "/datatable/group/add_users/" + group_id
});
```

This is giving me the correct message, but squished inside the first column:

[image]

Is there any way I can apply this message to fit over all of the columns?

Edit: my ajax result is an empty data row `{"data":[]}`, could that make a difference?

Comment: It's Working https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/44/  you have extra code??

Comment: strange, my ajax result is an empty data row `{"data":[]}`, could that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in DataTables: [DataTables Bug](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34971/datatable-empty-message-loading-in-first-column-only).

Try using nigtly builds or a newer version of DataTables.